# Is there a way to float every line in a file in python and then store those lines as a variable?

Tags: python

Here is the problem im having. I have a file with just numbers and would like to convert every line to a float and then read and store every line as a variable so i can do mathematic functions with them later.

This is my current code:

```
file = open("testfile.txt", "r")
var1 = file.readline(1)
var2 =  file.readline(2)
var3 =  file.readline(3)
var4 =  file.readline(4)
var5 = float(var1) + float(var2) + float(var3) + float(var4)
print(var5)
```

Every time I try to run it, it returns the error "cannot convert string to float".

Any and all suggestions would be greatly appreciated! 
Thanks and have a good day!

**EDIT**

Upon request, here is the testfile that am i using:

```
1
6
20
39
```

Comment: Can you post the test file you are using?

Comment: Should be a problem with `new line` symbols!

Comment: You should probably think more about using a variable for each line. If they have meaning they should be named appropriately. If they are just a sequence, you would be better putting them into a sequence e.g. `numbers = [float(v) for v in f]` and then reference them by index e.g. `numbers[0]` or collectively such as `sum(numbers)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

readline() function's first arg is the maximum characters to read, so here is how i fixed your code:

```
file = open("testfile.txt", "r")
var1 = file.readline().strip()
var2 =  file.readline().strip()
var3 =  file.readline().strip()
var4 =  file.readline().strip()
var5 = float(var1) + float(var2) + float(var3) + float(var4)
print(var5)
```

note: strip method is to remove \n from the line.

Comment: Gets somewhat crazy if there's loads of lines :)

Comment: @JonClements so need a loop, the above answer is what you are looking for

Comment: Thanks Esmail! Tried this and it works beautifully!

Comment: `float` doesn't care if whitespace has been stripped or not

Answer (score 3):

Edited: as @Jon Clements mentioned.
You don't want to pass in number for `readline` method since it'll only read that many bytes as well as newline character.

Also, unless you know the number of lines, you might want to use something like `list` to store the floats as following:

```
with open('testfile.txt') as f:
    f_list = [float(s) for s in f]
```

Comment: I do know how many lines there will be. The max number of lines will be 52